# Java, how to sort char alphabetically in Comparator

Tags: java, comparator

I am trying to built a maxheap of characters. First sort by frequency, if frequency is same, then sort alphabetically.

```java
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     char c = s.charAt(i);
     map.put(c, map.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);
}

Queue<Character> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Character>(){
  @Override
  public int compare(Character c1, Character c2){
   if(map.get(c1) == map.get(c2)){
     return c1 < c2 ? -1 : (c1 == c2 ? 0 : 1);
     //return (char)c1 - (char)c2; same output
   }
   return map.get(c2) - map.get(c1);
  }
});

for(char key : map.keySet()){
   pq.offer(key);
   System.out.println(key + " has freq " + map.get(key));
}

while(!pq.isEmpty()) {
     System.out.print(pq.poll() + " ");
}
```

I put 26 letters into this maxheap, and each letter has same frequency 5000.

But the output order is 'a', 'z', 'y', 'x'...., 'c', 'b'.
[image]

when frequency of each char is 5, the order is correct. 
[image]

I don't understand why the output with frequency 5000 is like this. How can I get a right order?

Comment: Where is `map` being defined?

Comment: Write your full code please

Comment: Use `equals()` to compare objects, not `==`.

Comment: @shmosel   I tried, doesn't work

Comment: When your `Integer`s are 5000, they are all different objects, so `map.get(c1) == map.get(c2)` is false.  When they are 5, they are all the same object due to a optimization in Java, and in that case `map.get(c1) == map.get(c2)` is true.

Comment: @MattTimmermans  Got it.Thank you so much!

Comment: Note also that `compute` is simpler and more reliable for your use case, and you should look at the builder utilities in `Comparator` (e.g., `Comparator.comparingInt(Map::get).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())`.

Comment: @chrylis I didn't know these methods before, thank you! I learned a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that all frequencies are the same, your if statement is wrong. You could use built-in methods to compare the objects and return the results

```
Integer f1 = map.get(c1);
Integer f2 = map.get(c2);
int x = f1.compareTo(f2)
if(x == 0){
    return Character.compare(c1, c2);
}
return x;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two `Integer` instances via `==` with the `if(map.get(c1) == map.get(c2))` statement. The reason why it works when the frequency is five, is that there is a mandatory caching for autoboxing values in the -128…+127 range. When the frequency is 5000, the identity of the `Integer` objects is unspecified and equal objects may have different identities.

One fix would be to use equals instead. The other is to stop implementing `Comparator` manually and use the factory methods. Together with other improvements, your code simplifies to

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     map.merge(s.charAt(i), 1, Integer::sum);
}

Queue<Character> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(
    Comparator.<Character>comparingInt(map::get).reversed()
        .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())
);

map.forEach((key, freq) -> {
   pq.offer(key);
   System.out.println(key + " has freq " + freq);
});

while(!pq.isEmpty()) {
     System.out.print(pq.poll() + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can compare two objects with .equals() method. it will return a Boolean value. if you want to hard code comparison then assign a integer value to each alphabet(total 26 variables) and compare their integer value and you'll know which one to place where.